# How to Bin/Count based on dates in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a python series which contains datetime.date objects ranging from 1/2013 to 12/2015 which is the month a product was sold. What I would like to do is count and bin by month the number of products sold.

Is there an efficient way of doing this with pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using datetime64, that is first apply `pd.to_datetime` on the index. If you set this as an index then you can use resample:

```
In [11]: s = pd.date_range('2015-01', '2015-03', freq='5D')  # DatetimeIndex

In [12]: pd.Series(1, index=s).resample('M', how='count')
Out[12]:
2015-01-31    7
2015-02-28    5
2015-03-31    1
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This works perfectly for my application and is much more succinct then my current approach. I was converting to datetimeindex then creating three additional columns in my DF for days, months, and years and utilizing groupby.

Comment: What are the differences between the pandas datetimeindex objects and python's native datetime objects?

Comment: @user5374436 pandas Timestamp/DatetimeIndex uses numpy's datetime64 under the hood, which is basically justs int64 with time zone information (which is attached to the entire array rather than a specific object - as it is with datetime.datetime). datetime.datetime are a lot less efficient since they are python objects.

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason why I couldn't use s.to_series ? Thanks for the pointers, reading some additional documentation has been helpful.

Comment: @user5374436 you can, one annoying thing with using this is that it creates a copy of the datetime (in both index and values)... thinking about it it's probably not that relevant performance wise. They both work!